# Spring - ResponseEntity not being used

Tags: java, spring, rest

New to Spring, so I want to return either a 400 or a 201 (Created) with a REST endpoint, but right now it only returns an empty 200 response via Postman.

**SampleService.java**

```java
@Service
public class SampleService {

    private SampleRepository sampleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SampleService(SampleRepository sampleRepository) {
        this.sampleRepository = sampleRepository;
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Response> registerData(Data data) {
        Optional<SampleData> dataOptional = sampleRepository.findDataByName(data.getName());

        if(dataOptional.isPresent()) {
            // Returns blank 200 response
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new Error(
                            "Bad Request",
                            "Data already exists."
                    ),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
            );
        }

        sampleRepository.save(data);

        // Returns blank 200 response
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                .body(
                    // I haven't got far to creating a response, so do not mind the "Error".
                    new Error("Created", "Stand-in until created proper response")
                );
    }
}
```

**Response.java**

```java
public interface Response {}
```

**Error.java**

```java
public class Error implements Response {
    private String errorType;
    private String errorMessage;

    public Error(String errorType, String errorMessage) {
        this.errorType = errorType;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public String getErrorType() {
        return errorType;
    }

    public void setErrorType(String errorType) {
        this.errorType = errorType;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

If anyone needs anything else, let me know, but this should be enough to cover.

Comment: You need to add the **controllar layer**.

Comment: You are right, and that did it.

Answer (score 0):

As I stated, new to Spring, and forgot to change the return type for my controller layer:

**SampleController.java**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Response> createData(@RequestBody Data data) {
    return this.sampleService.registerData(data);
}
```